# how to set a variable name dynamic in xsl

Tags: xslt

following is my code where i want to give the hidden variable and assign the value for it to access later.

```
 <xsl:for-each select="//Root/Record">
     <xsl:if test="(@CIMtrek_accountlist_customer_number != '') ">
     <option style="padding:5px;">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">>
    <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="(position() mod 2) = 0">
            AlternateRowOne
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
AlternateRowTwo
</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:attribute>
// here i want to set hidden varialble and assign the value for it
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
                    <xsl:value-of
            select="@CIMtrek_accountlist_customer_number" /></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-select="@CIMtrek_accountlist_customer_number" />
                </option>
                </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
```

the variable name will be some thing similar to like this

```
<input type="hidden"
name="hdnDialogListCtrlPlaceholder_CIMtrek_DailyshipCo_Destination_"+i
id="hdnDialogListCtrlPlaceholder_CIMtrek_DailyshipCo_Destination_"+i
 />

where i =0
and i++;

name_1
name_2
name_n
```

is it possible to use : `<FieldRef Name="<FieldInternalName>" Explicit="TRUE"/>`
how to do this in xsl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically achieve recursion in the following manner.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="recur">
            <xsl:with-param name="max_recursions" select="5"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="recur">
        <xsl:param name="n">0</xsl:param>
        <xsl:param name="max_recursions"/>
        REPEATING UNIT HERE
        <xsl:if test="$max_recursions != $n">
            <xsl:call-template name="recur">
                <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n + 1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="max_recursions" select="$max_recursions"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It isn't often advised though and you can usually achieve much faster, more succinct and more readable code through a well constructed XPath.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to write procedural code in XSLT, and that won't work. If you explain what transformation you want to perform (what's the input, what's the output, and how are they related?) then we can show you how to do it "the XSLT way", that is, declaratively.